# How do I set a function in another node in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript, duck-typing

I have a custom integrator written in a parent node's script, and I need to put it on multiple child nodes.

I read Godot's intro to GDScript and what it said about duck typing. From what I understood, I thought i could just do this:

```
child_obj._integrate_forces = my_integrator
```

But this freezes the app and gives a "property doesn't exist in node" error. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: I'll leave the question open but I solved it by just having a script in each child that calls the parent function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I set a function in another node in Godot?

You can't.

I do not know how you deduced this from duck-typing, but no... GDScript objects do have methods, not just properties that happen to have functions (which you would find, for example, in JavaScript).

You could place your method in a separate Script (perhaps make it an `static func`, or make the script an autoload, or some Node you know will always be available - *which is what you did*) and call it.

Alternatively, if it makes sense, you could use inheritance.